# Weird behavior with SQL UPDATE statement on DBF

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb, dbf

i'm really stuck on a apparently simple statement.

I'm working on a DBF table. When I open the file in a program called "DBF Viewer 2000", it states that the file is a "FoxBase+/dBASE III PLUSE, no memo".

If i run this VB.NET code

```
        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & opt.path & "\" & ";Extended Properties=dBase III;"
        Dim oledbAdapterIns As New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim InsConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        oledbAdapterIns = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        InsConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        Try
            InsConnection.Open()
            Dim s As String
            s = "UPDATE LIBRIAZ SET LIBRIAZ.ULTNUM=6 WHERE LIBRIAZ.REGISTRO='CW' AND LIBRIAZ.ANNO='2011' AND LIBRIAZ.CHIAVE='ORD_REG'"
            oledbAdapterIns.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(s, InsConnection)
            Dim rows As Integer = oledbAdapterIns.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Writeline(ex.Message)
        End Try
        oledbAdapterIns.Dispose()
        InsConnection.Dispose()
```

it runs without error BUT not updating the table.

Now comes the weird: if I remove one of the three conditions

```
LIBRIAZ.REGISTRO='CW' AND LIBRIAZ.ANNO='2011' AND LIBRIAZ.CHIAVE='ORD_REG'
```

for example

```
LIBRIAZ.ANNO='2011' AND LIBRIAZ.CHIAVE='ORD_REG'
```

the UPDATE works, setting LIBRIAZ.ULTNUM to 6

It's not a matter of which condition i remove, because it's enough to remove one of them to get the UPDATE working.

It's days I'm trying to figure why this behavior... now i'm pretty desperate.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: OK, is there at least 1 record meeting all conditions?

Comment: Yes, sure: the expected result is one result.

Comment: Did no one has before a similiar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that hits me is your first comment about "no memo".  When a dbf file has a memo field (like a blob in other SQL to store larger non-standard data elements like embedded pictures, Excel files, XML, or whatever).  The files "sets" would be such as

```
YourTable.dbf  (main table)
YourTable.cdx  (index file associated with just this table)
YourTable.fpt  (memo file associated with just this table)
```

The main .dbf has a file pointer system that is an offset in bytes in the .FPT file where it's contents are stored (if applicable).  So, I would see about finding that missing / corrupted .fpt file first.

Next, in your update statement, since you are only doing a direct update and not a correlated update based on another table, you don't need to ALIAS every field...  Try stripping down to...

```
s = "UPDATE LIBRIAZ SET ULTNUM = 6 WHERE REGISTRO='CW' AND ANNO='2011' AND CHIAVE='ORD_REG'"
```

Comment: In my case i have LIBRIAZ.DBF and LIBRIAZ.MDX.
I already tried 
s = "UPDATE LIBRIAZ SET ULTNUM = 6 WHERE REGISTRO='CW' AND ANNO='2011' AND CHIAVE='ORD_REG'" 
without success...

Comment: @Luigi, for dbase based files... see if there's a .dbt file for the memo content...